# In Visual Studio how to give relative path of a .lib file in project properties

Tags: visual-studio, relative-path

I am building a project using Visual Studio. The project has a dependency on a lib file generated by another project. This project is there is the parent directory of the actual project I am building.

To be more clear, 
I have a "ParentDir" which has two subDirectories Project1 and Project2 under it. 
Now Project1 depends on lib generated by Project2.

In the properties of Project1, I am trying to give a relative path using 
$(SolutionDir)/../ParentDir/Project2/Debug 
But this does not seem to work.

Can you tell me where i am going wrong, or suggest the correct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the dependant project to your solution and set it as a dependency of the other project using project properties. Then it just magically works ;).

A solution is just a file that describes a set of related (interconnected) projects and the relation between them, so this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Here is the article that explains how to create dependencies. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your current dir is your $(ProjectDir), that is where .vcproj file is.

So, just write ../Project2/Debug, that will do.

Even better, write ../Project2/$(ConfigurationName) for all configurations

thus you will be always linking to the correct version of that lib.

Answer (score 1):

I think Visual Studio does not expand the relative path properly when the ".." is placed somewhere in the middle of the path string. It only knows how to expand ..{sub-path}.